# Is it possible to share Image in Google cloud without granting roles/compute.imageUser role?

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Sharing image in Google Cloud Platform after some time testing, not exactly at the time of Instance Image creation.

I've already read a lot of Google Documentation such as https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects. But here explains, that images can be shared based on granting roles and it will be shared directly at the time of creation if member has appropriate role. I would like to do some tests and if tests passed only in this case share image with other members.

Could you please share with me any information if you have already faced with such problem?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to have an image shared to some users only after you've tested it.

Without further explanation of your use case, why don't you do your tests, make sure everything is ok with your image and then [export](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/image-management-best-practices#manual_baking) it as a custom image and share it?  If you wanna restrict the users that have access to it have a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

Give a bit more info and we can think of other things.

Comment: Hi @eespinola! Thanks for your answer. Let me explain a bit. Currently I can build an instance with Jenkins pipeline in GCP, also I can create an image with Packer after it. Next step - I should check if instance builds successfully from created AMI. And only if everything Ok I want to share image with different projects. Currently we don't have an opportunity to share image to project, we can share only to defined member by granting role. So, main concern - I want to share only tested AMIs with different members, but if they have Compute Image Role -they will see not tested images.

Comment: Hi, maybe using Container-Registry fits your needs, you can make an image public or private depending on what you want to share or not. Have a look at access-control for container-registry. You could try to make different buckets for different users that you want to give access to, this would do the part of not having them see all your images. Let me know. [Access-Control](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control)